# How to get new Google Form responses to take on non-form functions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, worksheet-function, google-sheets-custom-function

I developed a Google Form that copies responses to a linked output spreadsheet in Google Sheets.

In addition to the columns created by the form question/responses themselves, I've added additional custom columns. These columns contain functions (and formatting) to manipulate and utilize the response data for a script I wrote. I copied the generic functions through each row for these additional columns.

Everything works as I expect, except....

Every time another user fills out the form (i.e., every new response I receive), a new row is created in my Google spreadsheet instead of simply "adding" to my next function-containing row. As a result, the new response rows are added *without the generic functions/formatting*, leaving my previously "set up" rows below the newly added response row.

[image]

**Is there some way to have new response rows be created in a way that incorporates functions in the non-form column cells?**

- In other words, I don't want to have to copy functions into cells of new rows *every time* a new response is generated, but instead to have these functions "auto-fill."

Answer (score 2):

This post is eight months old as I respond here, but the basic answer is, *Yes: use an array formula in the first cell of those columns.*

I don't know what your custom functions do or if they would involve any calculations that don't work with arrays, but as written, these formulas would work:

In E1: `=ArrayFormula({"Custom Column 1";IF(A2:A="","",Function(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C)})`

In F1: `=ArrayFormula({"Custom Column 2";IF(A2:A="","",Function(A2:A,E2:E)})`

Comment: Thanks, Erik. I'll have to check in on this to see if it works out for my case (which I'll have to brush some dust off to check...).

Comment: theforestcologist, if you try it and it doesn't work, it's because you've got certain parts of your function that conflict with array use. There is almost always a way to rework a formula so that it does work with a single-cell array, however. If this is the case when you try it, I'm happy to take a look at your Google doc (post it here) and suggest an alternative.